# How to access a particular String on an ArrayList <String[]>?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have this piece of code:

```
ArrayList <String[]> seleccionar(String query){
    ArrayList lista = new ArrayList <>();
    try{
        //Obtener datos de la base
        Statement cmd = cnx.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = cmd.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData resMetaData = res.getMetaData();
        int nColumnas = resMetaData.getColumnCount();
        while(res.next()) {
            ArrayList reg = new ArrayList <>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= nColumnas; i++) {
                reg.add(res.getString(i));
            }
            String[] registro = new String[reg.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < reg.size(); i++) {
                registro[i] = reg.get(i).toString();
                //System.out.print(registro [i] + " ");
            }
            lista.add(registro);
            //System.out.println("Añadido a lista.");
        }
        res.close();
        cmd.close(); 
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error en el comando a BD");

    }
    return lista;
}
```

But `ArrayList` makes every `String[]` added to `lista` into an `Object`, and I can't use it as a `String[]` anymore. I need to be able to access every `String` inside the `String[]` inside the `Arraylist`.

What should I do? Is using `ArrayList` the wrong choice? Or am I missing some functionality on `ArrayList`?

All my knowledge is from experimentation and concepts read from here and there, so I have quite a few holes in it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: You could make a `List<List<String>>` instead since you know how to access a list. It's not clear why you need an array

Comment: Use `ArrayList<String[]>` everywhere you have the plain `ArrayList`. A plain `ArrayList` is called a raw type and it's the same as not using generics.

Comment: What is the purpose of `reg`? You can skip that arraylist and use `new String[nColumnas];`...

Comment: Thanks for you answers, as for not using reg you're right, i could just use new String, thanks. As for using a List<List<String> I dont know if its valid because in this particular exercise i'm given the classes with the methods and method types, and i'm not supposed to change it from an ArrayList <String[]>.